# Android: is it possible to have multiple separate Canvas layers, which I can merge to one?

Tags: android, canvas, layer

Is it possible to have multiple separate [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) layers, which I can merge to one? Similar to what I'd do in photoshop?

---

**Update:**

Some explanation why I'd like to have something like that:
`Layer1` might hold something that has been created by a complex and CPU expensive algorithm while the other layer, `Layer2`, is something that just goes on top of that, but changes regularly, e.g. when a user touches the interface. For that I don't want to go through the whole process of drawing the underlaying `Layer1` again, but just make the changes to `Layer2` and then "merge" them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can have something like a FrameLayout in which you override onDraw() and have server sub-elements in which you also override onDraw().

This might give you the effect you want.